# how to assign the background image using javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the background image using javascript. and i am taking the below approach:

```
document.getElementById("country").style.backgroundImage="url('images/dropdown.jpg')";
```

But its not working.

Could you please help me in this where is the error?

Comment: Your JS is **perfect**. Good luck! (just make sure your path to the `images` folder is right. If You're inside some `js` folder you might want to lookback `../` some folders...)

Comment: Yeah, like @RokoC.Buljan said, syntax wise you're good. How exactly is it "not working"? Are you seeing errors in the console?

Comment: Sometimes I also make errors like `.jpg` vs `.png` ... just make sure you got it all right.

Comment: yes i am in 'js' folder and i have used "url('../images/dropdown.jpg')" also.
but its not working

Comment: hands tied. Sorry. Open up console as @StevenSchobert said and see all your errors. Get accustomed with `console`, will be your best friend for a while.

Comment: the error in the console is :
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: its fixed now , i was missing the closing } of the function. but now its giving me the error FILE_NOT_FOUND. i am using the same url in my css file.

css file is also in the 'css' folder and its working for the css.

Comment: @SPGuar The paths in your CSS are relative to **that CSS** file. The path in your JS file here is going to be relative to page that its currently being loaded at. You might try using an absolute path (starting with `/images/dropdown.jpg`) if you are loading this script across multiple pages.

Comment: thanks for your hint @StevenSchobert . i have modified my url to images/dropdown.jpg and now its working fine. Thanks a lot